# Postgresql - How to change xml data type to integer when using xpath in select

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I try to select values from one xml field and insert selected values to another table field with integer type.

QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO "Match" 
select 
unnest(xpath('./game/id/text()', "File"))
FROM "Files"
```

Select works fine, but when I try to insert, then error occurs:

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type xml
LINE 3: unnest(xpath('./game/id/text()', "File")),

HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

When I try to change xml type with cast, then I get another error:

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  cannot cast type xml to integer
LINE 3: cast(unnest(xpath('./game/id/text()', "File"))as integer)
```

And when I try to change type with XMLSERIALIZE, then another error occurs:

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  argument of XMLSERIALIZE must not return a set
LINE 3: XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT unnest(xpath('./game/id/text()', "File"...
```

**How can I insert selected values to another table?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You start by selecting the text in the XML "id" nodes:

```
xpath('game/id/text()', col1)
```

This returns an array, which you unnest, resulting in between zero or more rows:

```
unnest(xpath('game/id/text()', col1))
```

A `cross join lateral` allows you to run `unnest(xpath(...))` for every row in the table:

```
cross join lateral
        unnest(xpath('game/id/text()', col1)) xp(id)
```

Finally, Postgres can't convert XML to a number.  You need an intermediate conversion to text:

```
select  id::text::int
from    YourTable
cross join lateral
        unnest(xpath('game/id/text()', col1)) xp(id)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b6c0/1/0)